# Segments are constantly changing

Tags: email, segment, sendy

I would like to get help about an issue that we have been experiencing on our Sendy system and that we have not been able to resolve for a while. We recently migrated the sendy system to a more powerful server. However, segment schedules do not work properly after this process. I am sending you a video attached. As you can see, the number of segments is constantly changing. However, there is no change in our systems. In addition, when we check the segments, we see that it does not comply with the necessary rules.

Regards

[image]

Sample Video
https://www.veed.io/view/5f20a795-e560-4f82-91b3-df949b7e6065?sharingWidget=true

Answer (score 0):

This is due to wrong cronjob setup. Sendy cronjob for segments supposed to run every 15 minutes. Sendy starts to count segments from the top every time cron is running. So if you keeping refreshing the page, you'll see stats getting updated in real time.

And when you have cronjob run every minute, Sendy will never stop counting segments and you'll see numbers consistently changing. This is what's happening with your Sendy segments.

Source: [Sendy List Segment Error](https://vpsfix.com/community/internet-marketing/sendy-list-segment-error-segments-are-constantly-changing/)